# Maven in eclipse: changes in children doesn't show in parent's files

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, maven, parent-child

I'm using maven in eclipse (M2Eclipse), and I have a multi-module project which I used 'checkout as a maven project' to bring it to my workspace.

The structure seems to be flat in eclipse and it has duplicate of children: parent is there with all the children nested in it as folders (doesn't show the packages inside children as a package should look like, but has them as nested ordinary folders), also, all the children show up as independent projects beside the parent (under the children projects: the packages are shown as they should, the package icon is shown and it is dot notation).

So, when I change a file in a child project, the corresponding file in the parent's subfolders also changes (I can see them both in eclipse).

It has always worked for me, and I could commit my changes by just committing the parent project.

But, it suddenly changed. I have changed a lot of files in children's projects, but the changes don't show in the parent's project and I cannot commit them all in one commit, I will have to commit each child one by one which adds a lot of commits and increases the version number unnecessarily. 
Also, it makes me worried that the assembly will also not take the latest changes-> I haven't tried it though.

I will appreciate any help, I get stuck with problems with maven frequently!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Things don't suddenly change. Did you install any new plug-ins? Check your install history.

Did you change anything in the preferences? Does the same happen with a fresh install of Eclipse? Does it change when you import the preferences into a clean install?

Which version control system do you use?

Comment: you're right, it shouldn't have been sudden.. I don't know what I changed (long time now), but I managed to get it to normal by updating my eclipse plug-ins (m2eclipse and subclipse). But, I know I didn't install any new plugin and I didn't change preferences. I didn't try your suggestions though, because it became normal before I got your reply.

Answer (score 0):

have you executed a mvn install on the sub-module projects? Please try to delete you m2 repository directory.

It'seems the problems is that the jars sub-modules files are not updated in the repo directory.